# Peculiar issue with replaceAll method in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have input as below:

```
Input: 6jVYY3Xnqt<>:"/\|?*GjznpnRQSb
testInput = testInput.replaceAll("[<>:/\\\"|?*]", "-");
output: 6jVYY3Xnqt----\---GjznpnRQSb
```

But if I do:

```
testInput = testInput.replaceAll("[<>:/\"|?*]", "-");
testInput = testInput.replace("\\", "-");
output: 6jVYY3Xnqt--------GjznpnRQSb
```

Is this a bug in java 7? Why is `replaceAll` not taking the `\` character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double escape the backslash in your regular expression, once for the string literal and once for the regular expression:

```
testInput= testInput.replaceAll("[<>:/\\\\\"|?*]", "-");
//                                    ^^^^
//                                    Represents one backslash
```